# getting map markers to show from data in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, native

I'm using firebase to host user lat and longitude information. I want to use this info to show on google map markers. Does anyone know how aggregate this data into an array and pull it from firebase? Any help will be much appreciated. I'm writing in javascript react native.

```
markerDetails(){
    var markers = [];
    var markerRef = firebase.database().ref('listings');
    markerRef.on('value', function(snapShot) {
      markers = snapShot.val();
      console.log(rentalMarkers)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code take the value from server and and append it to the location array

```
    var locations = [  ];    
     // call php array
      var latitude = <?php echo json_encode($latitude); ?>;
      var longitude = <?php echo json_encode($longitude); ?>;  
    for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
      locations.push(["current",latitude[i], longitude[i]]);
    }
var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
          var labelIndex = 0;
     var marker;
          function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 5,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.289774217827633, 76.30976921188685)
            });
```

Hope this might help...